# Long Outputs Inside Emacs Cider Repl Buffers

Tags: emacs, clojure, read-eval-print-loop, cider

When using Emacs with the Cider plug-in, moving inside the REPL buffer gets incredibly slow, when there was accidently printed a huge amount of output to the REPL buffer.

- Is there a way to configure Leiningen (or nrepl?) to limit the number
  of lines that are allowed to be printed by one evaluation in the
  repl?
- Is there maybe a way to let Emacs clear the buffer after the output
  happened?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried setting `*print-length*`?
See [this](https://docs.cider.mx/cider/repl/basic_usage.html) documentation and search for 'Limiting output in the REPL'.